# Flutter display api response as pdf

Tags: flutter, pdf

I am calling an api to download an invoice in pdf form. I get a invoice pdf as response, When I save and try to display the pdf I get a white screen instead of the actual invoice pdf, if I use Postman to call the same api I can view the invoice pdf.

This is how the response looks like

```
%PDF-1.4
%âã
1 0 obj
<<
/Title ()
/Creator (��wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5)
/Producer (��Qt 5.12.8)
/CreationDate (D:20230509055840Z)
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/SA true
/SM 0.02
/ca 1.0
/CA 1.0
/AIS false
/SMask /None>>
endobj
5 0 obj
[/Pattern /DeviceRGB]
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
```

This is not the complete response but just a few lines.

I am using dio to fetch the invoice. Here is the code

```
 var response = await Dio().post(
        downloadInvoice.value,
        data: {'id': invoiceID},
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            "authorization": "Bearer $accessToken",
          },
        ),
      );
```

This is the code I use to save the file on the device and display the pdf

```
  if (response != null) {
        var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        final filePath = "${dir.path}/$filename.pdf";

        File file = File(filePath);
        try {
          if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
            printInfo('permission granted');
            await file.writeAsString(response.data);
            pdfPath.set(file.path);
            showBottomSheet(context!, invoiceRef, pdfPath.value);
          } else {
            Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
              Permission.storage,
            ].request();
            print(statuses[Permission.storage]);
            await Permission.storage.request();
            printInfo('request permission');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          print(error);
          print(error);
        }
        print(pdfPath);
      }
```

I am using [flutter_pdfview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview) to display the pdf by providing the path. The displayed data is a white screen. How can correctly display the invoice pdf

Answer (score 0):

Add one line in option, it should work. Like this

```
options: Options(
      headers: {
       "authorization": "Bearer $accessToken",
      },
      responseType: ResponseType.bytes
    )
```